# Local Time To UTC time pytz

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7, pytz

I converted python datetime with help of pytz.

Convertion is like this

> 2013-08-23T09:53:03 to 2013-08-23T15:23:03+05:30 (time is changed
>   according timezone)

now the problem is "At at another loaction i get **time as string**  2013-08-23T15:23:03+05:30 how can i convert this string to 2013-08-23T09:53:03

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the very useful dateutil package

```
from dateutil import parser
import pytz
UTC = pytz.timezone('UTC')
date = parser.parse("2013-08-23T15:23:03+05:30")
dateutc = date.astimezone(UTC)
print dateutc.isoformat() 
# or user strptime to have in the format you want (without time zone)
print dateutc.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```